# CodeNameOne : when modifying default theme -> issue on device

Tags: codenameone

I use codenameOne to build an mobile app. On the simulator the app works fine.

The app works fine on device when i use a default theme but when i modify it, i have white pages.

Can somebody help?

On the simulator:
[image]

On the device (Tablet Sumsung galaxy 10.1) everything is white:
[image]

Comment: No code, no help. Pictures are essentially useless, other than for going "oooh, pretty"

Comment: i m looking for someone who experienced same thing. How can i debug codenameone on device ? i used GUI BUILDER and i think the theme file is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with background gradient style UIID's on Android.

However, you should probably not use background theme gradients as explained [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/theme-basics.html). They are less efficient than background images by a big margin.

Comment: Thank you very much ! That s unfortunate but i should manage in a different way.